# How to resolve PostgreSQL issue when using Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a project which is built from several maven modules. These modules include logic to clear down, populate and validate the contents of a PostgreSQL database.

The lower level modules all work fine, but my top level Spring Boot Application is currently failing due to the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:202)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:99)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findByUserNameIgnoreCase(Unknown Source)
at org.credmins.cornerstone.model.initialise.CornerstoneDBInit.createItemsIfNoKeyUsersExist(CornerstoneDBInit.java:69)
at org.credmins.cornerstone.model.initialise.RunDBInitialiserWhenNeeded.onApplicationEvent(RunDBInitialiserWhenNeeded.java:21)
at org.credmins.cornerstone.model.initialise.RunDBInitialiserWhenNeeded.onApplicationEvent(RunDBInitialiserWhenNeeded.java:16)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:775)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column userrecord0_.created_by_user_uuid does not exist
  Position: 36
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065
```

The stack trace is pointing me to this key line:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column userrecord0_.created_by_user_uuid does not exist
```

The test which fails is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CornerstoneApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CornerstoneApplicationTest {

@Test    
public void contextLoads() {  }
}
```

The application is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CornerstoneApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CornerstoneApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Looking at the underlying data, the first data record in the *userrecord* file does not have a created_by_user_uuid, but looking at the entity record, this field is not mandatory

UserRecord:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserRecord extends AbstractKeyedRecord implements Record {

    @Nonnull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;
    @Nonnull
    private String firstName;
    @Nonnull
    private String lastName;
<truncated>
```

AbstractKeyedRecord:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractKeyedRecord extends AbstractRecord {
    @Id
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;
<truncated>
```

AbstractRecord:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractRecord implements Serializable, Record {
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime createdDate;
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "pg-uuid")
private UUID createdByUserUuid;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime lastUpdatedDate;
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "pg-uuid")
private UUID lastUpdatedUserUuid;

public AbstractRecord() {
}
<truncated>
```

Record:

```
public interface Record {}
```

Probably the most frustrating thing of all is that I have had this working before, but recently moved from xml config files to use config classes, and the ApplicationTest has not worked since.

So, my question is can anyone suggest steps I could take to resolve resolve this issue ?

Comment: **Update** 
After proof reading my question above, i wondered "What happens if I ensure that valid data is in that field" ?
I tried it out, and I get exactly the same result:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column userrecord0_.created_by_user_uuid does not exist

Comment: Why do you think that the column "created_by_user_uuid "is not mandatory?

Comment: @Cyril I _THINK_ that the column is not mandatory, because I have never stated that it **IS** mandatory. (I think optional by default.) Also, I have tests in previous Maven modules which create and delete users, and these are fine without that field being present.

Comment: Declared columns are mandatory (but nullable) by default. I'm not aware that it's possible to make DB columns optional.

Comment: @Cyril : Ah, the penny drops. The error message is saying that the column is missing, rather than that the column is null. I can see the column in pgAdmin, on the connection that I think I am using, so I must be going somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are connecting to some other DB that doesn't have the 'created_by_user_uuid' column. Especially because it was working with XML config.
Check your database connection configuration. You could set the DB connection password to a wrong password to be sure that you are really connecting to the configured DB.